# Nuxt Device Detection with Generate

Tags: nuxt.js, device-detection

I installed nuxtjs/device and in localhost it works well and I get what I wanted with ctx.isMobile. But I use nuxt generate and when I deploy my app. it doesnt work. So for this module to work must there be a server? or is there a way to detect device in static generate mode?.

I added this on my modules like this

```
modules: [
   '@nuxtjs/device',
 ]
```

and I use it in my components like this

```
this.$device.isMobile
```

and like this

```
ctx.isMobile
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at this part of @nuxtjs/device's documentation

https://github.com/nuxt-community/device-module#options

`defaultUserAgent` option can be used for `npm run generate`.

```js
{
  modules: [
    [
      '@nuxtjs/device',
      {defaultUserAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 6 Build/LYZ28E) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.39 Mobile Safari/537.36'}
    ]
  ]
}
```

It says to use `defaultUserAgent` option to make it work with nuxt generate mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It might be used to set defaultuseragent, which means whatever device enters the website will be regarded as whatever value is provided in defaultuseragent. which is not really usefull in my opinion.

Comment: for static mode there's not easy way to detect user device before app initialization.

Comment: Did you try doing this before concluding that this won't work for static mode? May be the way nuxt/device module is implemented, it requires us to set defaultUserAgent in order to make it work in static mode. Just check it, and let me know.